# Having object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xamarin

So basicly im getting this error and its pretty straightforward what it means, my trouble is understanding where it is. The stack trace only points to this method.

```
async Task GetInfo(string response)
    {
        var newData= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(response);
        this.NewData= newData;
        this.MyDataForm.NewData= this.NewData;
        if (this.NewData.Age!= this.Age|| this.NewData.Id!= this.Id)
        {

                await RequestNewData();
        }
        else
        {
//TODO
        }
    }
```

This method is inside a try catch within the `RequestNewData();` Right now my only guess for what may have been throwing this null exception is that `MyDataForm` is null at some point.

Comment: the stack trace should point you to the specific line.  Or fire up the debugger and test every element to figure out who is null.  Are you sure DeserializeObject is not returning null?

Comment: @Jason i have errors being reported to appcenter and the stack trace in this specific error does not show me the line where the null occurs. Regarding your question i think no, this method is only called if the reponse.StatusCode is succesful. This dont happen everytime, it happens from time to time.

Comment: a successful response code does not mean that the JSON returned is valid, or matches your model, etc.

Comment: @Jason true but so how can this work fine most of the time and sometimes dont? wouldn´t that mean that the error would happen all the time if the DeserializeObject was returning null?

Comment: No idea.  Maybe the server just gives a funky response .001% of the time?  Maybe some data conditions return bad json, or json that is not deserializable into your model?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example